# Selenium error: java.awt.AWTException: headless environment

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, devtools

Can someone assist how to solve this issue (if possible to be solved)?

I am using **DevTools** for getting necessary token (in all automation tests). Tests are written in **Java (Selenium 4.16.1)**
In order to have them run on pipeline, must be in headless mode and in incognito mode, too.
But throws error: **java.awt.AWTException: headless environment**

Tried a lot of options in Chrome, but without any success. Chrome browser class looks like this:

```
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--enable-application-cache");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--allow-running-insecure-content");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--enable-automation");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=3222");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-infobars");

        String incognito = System.getProperty("incognito", "false");
        if (incognito.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--incognito");
        }

        String pathToDownl = System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\" + Constants. 
        $string("download.location");
        HashMap<String, Object> chromePre = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        chromePre.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
        chromePre.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
        chromePre.put("download.default_directory", pathToDownl);
        chromePre.put("profile.content_settings.exceptions.automatic_downloads.*.setting", 1);
        chromePre.put("safebrowsing.enabled", false);
        chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePre);
        //System.out.println(pathToDownl);

        
        if ($boolean("enableProxy")==true){
            chromeOptions.setCapability("proxy", setProxy());
        }
```